# Parameterized store procedures in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, ado.net, parameters

I'm getting an error when the 'insertcommand' is executed telling me that I'm missing the parameters for the stored procedure. Do I need to put the parameter names in the Sql statement after the procedure as if I were calling it in SQL? I saw an example online that just added the parameters like I have here, but this doesn't work?  I also put the sql state for the stored procedure below the 'AddRepair Sub'

---

```
Public Shared Sub AddRepair(ByVal repair As ClubRepair)

    Dim conn As SqlConnection = ClubRentalsDB.getconnection
    Dim insertcommand As New SqlCommand("AddRepair", conn)

    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", repair.Name)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", repair.MemberID)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", repair.PhoneNumber)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", repair.Email)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work", repair.WorkToBeDone)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specification", repair.Specification)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SoonestDate", repair.SoonestCompletion)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PromisedDate", repair.DatePromised)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClubType", repair.TypeOfClub)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GripType", repair.TypeOfGrip)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfClubs", repair.NumOfClubs)
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecialInstructions", repair.SpecialInstructions)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        insertcommand.ExecuteReader()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(messageBad & ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try   
End Sub
```

---

```
USE [ClubRentals]   
GO
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO  
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[AddRepair] (@Name Varchar(50), @ID varchar(20),
  @Phone varchar(50),@Email varchar(50), @Work varchar(20),@Specification varchar(MAX), 
  @SoonestDate date, @PromisedDate Date, @ClubType varchar(50), @Griptype varchar(50), 
  @NumOfClubs int, @SpecialInstructions varchar(MAX)) as

Insert into ClubRepair(Member_Name,Member_ID,Phone,Email,WorkToBeDone,Specification,
     SoonestPossibleCompletion,DatePromised,TypeOfClub, TypeOfGrips ,NumOfClubs,   
     SpecialInstructions)    

values(@Name, @ID, @Phone, @Email, @Work, @Specification,    
       @SoonestDate, @PromisedDate, @ClubType, @GripType,    
       @NumOfClubs,@SpecialInstructions)

GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm that every parameter value you are setting is not Nothing. Parameters with no value can cause the missing parameter error. There's a two-argument version of If() that helps:

```
insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specification", If(repair.Specification, ""))
```

this will return repair.Specification if it is not Nothing, and "" otherwise.

also, you should consider using Parameters.Add().Value() instead of .AddWithValue(), like so:

```
insertcommand.Parameters.Add("@ClubType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(repair.TypeOfClub, "")
```

This is really useful when you're working with types other than string.

Comment: Jeff Paulsen thanks. However I used the locals window while debugging to ensure the properties had value. What is the difference between .add and .addwithvalue?

Comment: .add lets you specify the sql type of the parameter, and its length.

Comment: Would I need to specify the length and type even though its already defined in the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. This is a GOOD thing. Two reasons - first, .AddWithValue always passes strings as NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR, which can lead to unicode conversion issues down the road. Second, .AddWithValue uses the length of the input string as the parameter length, rather than the one in the stored proc - this prevents reuse of the query execution plan nearly always.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting sqlcommand commandtype to storedprocedure.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to respect case sensitivity, for an example

```
    insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GripType", repair.TypeOfGrip)
```

is wrong

```
     insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Griptype", repair.TypeOfGrip)
```

is right

Comment: Fredou, I appreciate your input. But VB is not a case sensitive language,

Comment: @Matt Stewart, yes but SQL server might be, depending on the database configuration

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you're saying. This configuration of SQL isn't either.